# How to compare between rows that technically match, and verify between the two that one has "OptionA" and one has "OptionB" in a certain column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I’m comparing data and need to match rows to each other, or show that there is no match.  In this example, `Item1` and `Item2` are a match, `Item3` and `Item4` are a match, and `ItemM` and `ItemN` have no matches.

I am getting dates and amounts from two different sources that are feeding into columns B and E; columns C and F are only present to signify which source this row is coming from.  Please note, not every row will have a match, ie. `ItemM` & `ItemN`.  For all intents & purposes, the actual entries in B1:B2 are identical, same goes for B3:B4, E1:E2, and E3:E4 albeit 4 different numbers

In this example:

[image: example]

D1:D2 and G1:G2 both return `Y`.  The `Y` entries are calculated using a `COUNTIF` function to show if DateIdentifiers and AmtIdentifiers have near matches, but what I am looking for is a formula for column H to return either:

1. `Match` - D1 and G1 both equal `Y` AND the matching row includes the other Source (either column C or G `Item1`’s source does NOT equal `Item2`’s)
2. `Missing SourceX` - if either D1 or G1 does not equal `Y`, return the opposite of the source located in Column C (see example).

Sorry if this is confusing, I’ve been working on this spreadsheet for what seems like 15 hours total so far.  Please let me know if you have questions.  Also, please ignore the fact that the screenshot is from Excel 2011, I have 2010 at work but the formulas should work interchangeably.

Comment: Thanks for the inline image Adam!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
=IF(C1 = "Source1",IF(C2="Source2",IF(AND(D1="Y",G1="Y",D2="Y",G2="Y"),"Match","Missing Source2"),"Missing Source2"),IF(INDIRECT("C"&ROW()-1)="Source1",IF(AND(D1="Y",G1="Y",INDIRECT("D"&ROW()-1)="Y",INDIRECT("G"&ROW()-1)="Y"),"Match","Missing Source2"),"Missing Source1"))
```

Put that into H1 and copy it down.

The key to this is to figure out if you are on a Source1 row or a Source2 row and then look up or down accordingly.

If we are on a Source1 row, I use INDIRECT and ROW()-1 to look up to the row above it to see if it is a Source1 row or not. If it is that is good. Then we can check if the Ys are all present.

Comment: Sorry, they aren't necessarily in consecutive rows.  Sometimes we might have a row only from Source1 and no row for Source2 (so the next row would be Source1 for a new identifier).        Also, the rows might not always be odd from Source1 vs. even from Source2.

Comment: OK. Do you always have either Source1 or Source2 in column C?

Comment: Yes.  Always one or the other, never blank.

Comment: And never a Source2 by itself?

Comment: Yes, it will be possible to have a Source2 by itself without a matching identifier coming from Source1.  Then my output would be something along the lines of "Missing Source1" or something of the sort.

Comment: One more question, what happens if you have a Source1 without a Source2, followed immediately by a Source2 that had no Source1.

Comment: it would be ideal if they returned "Missing Source2" and "Missing Source1" respectively, as they would not have matching date or amount identifiers in columns B and E

Comment: Does having a Y indicate that a matching row is present?

Comment: Yes it does.  But each row needs two Ys (one in column D and one in column G) in order to match with another row (i.e. If the Date or Amt identifier doesn't have a near match, then there would be no Y in column D or G

Comment: I've updated my answer, hopefully that is what you need.

Comment: Thanks @dev1998, we're getting closer.  Now is there any way to get `H4` dependent on the Y values in two rows (row 4 which it already is, and row 3, the other matching item [4 "Y" values total])?  I'm trying to with a VLOOKUP, but it's only returning it's own row value (row 4, value "Match")

Comment: Looks great, thank you @dev1998.  This will definitely help clear up a few of my false negatives I am getting.  Much appreciated!